# Equalizing Sliders

Tags: swift, uitableview, uislider

I have a `UITableView` with a `UISlider` in each cell (please observe there may be more than two as in the example below!).

[image: Example 1]

My goal is to make it so that when you drag one of the sliders the other one will adjust so that the total value of all sliders is 100% at all times.

[image: Example 2]

Right now I'm using a delegate to handle the value of each slider, so that when a new value is set on the slider, it calls a delegate function which adjusts the other sliders accordingly.

This is what the cell class would look like:

```
class SliderCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    ...

    var id: String?
    var delegate: SliderDelegate?
    var value: Double! {
        didSet {
            slider.value = value
        }
    }
    ...

    private func sliderValueChanged(to newValue: Double) {
        // Values are between 0 and 1..
        self.value = delegate?.valueChanged(requestedValue: newValue, cellId: id)
    }

}
```

And this is the delegate:

```
class SliderDelegate {

    var allCells: [SliderCell]?
    ...

    func valueChanged(requestedValue: Double, cellId: String) -> Double {
        let minValue = Double() // ?
        let maxValue = Double() // ?

        ...

        let eachOtherCellOffset = Double() // ?

        for cell in allCells.filter { return $0.id != cellId } {
            cell.value += eachOtherCellOffset
        }

        return min(max(minValue, requestedValue), min(maxValue, requestedValue))
    }

}
```

Any suggestions on how I would go about calculating the min- and maxvalue of the cell? And how I can offset the other cells' values to account for the new value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365741/algorithm-to-always-sum-sliders-to-100-failing-due-to-zeroes

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504618/3-interconnected-sliders,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978404/uislider-maximum-values-adjustments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to always sum sliders to 100% failing due to zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365741/algorithm-to-always-sum-sliders-to-100-failing-due-to-zeroes)